# Create a Form inside a table using html

Tags: html, forms, html-table, using

I need to create a form for insurance Using table. I need in the correct position. Need some style. Should looks beautiful .. :) So please help .
Is there any tool or any other way to make it?

My Current Code is -

```
<html>
<body>
  <center>
<table>
  <tr id="idrow1"><td> First Name : <input type="text" name="firstname"> </td></tr>
  <tr id="idrow2"><td> Last Name : <input type="text" name="lastname">  </td></tr>
  <tr id="idrow3"><td> Age       : <input type="text" name="age"> </td></tr>
  <tr id="idrow3"><td> Email      : <input type="email" name="email"> </td></tr>
  :
  :
  :

</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google and you shall find. But try looking for CSS form design. The HTML above is old and <center> is deprecated.

Comment: Need Forms in table ..

Comment: Yes, you can have the form in a table if you wish, that still doesn't affect my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Bootstrap tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) and [Bootstrap horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) that gives you some prettya and easy styles.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table form-horizontal">
  <tr>
    <td class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-4 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail4" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Anyway you could use the form without tables if you want/can.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out and import css file for style in your html doc

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<table>
<br>
<tr id="idrow1"><td> First Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"> </td></tr>
<tr id="idrow2"><td> Last Name  : </td><td><input type="text" name="lastname">  </td></tr>
<tr id="idrow3"><td> Age        : </td><td><input type="text" name="age">       </td></tr>
<tr id="idrow4"><td> Email      : </td><td><input type="email" name="email">    </td></tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```